# remove first few characters in URL hash string

Tags: javascript, hash

I'm trying to figure out how to remove a certain part of a URL string, as in:

```
if (window.location.hash == '#super-super-product') { 
    change.window.location.hash.to.this: #product  // pseudo code, obviously
}
```

So, to remove "super-super-", which is the first 12 chars, and keep the rest, 
whatever it happens to be.

The following attempts produce no change whatsoever:

```
if (/^#checkout-counter-./.test(window.location.hash)){ // this works perfectly
    window.location.hash.substring(0, 11); // this does nothing
    window.location.hash.substr(1, 12);  // nothing
    window.location.hash.slice(0, 11);  // still nothing
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why check with regex then use string functions? You can use `str.replace(regex, '')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling substring or any other similar methods will only evaluate the function and return it without having any effects whatsoever. You need to assign the result to the window's hash.

`window.location.hash = window.location.hash.substring(0, 11);`

Answer (score 2):

You need to re-assign it. Otherwise the result is simply thrown away, as it's not assigned to anywhere meaningful.

```
window.location.hash = window.location.hash.substring(0, 11);
```